# Trouble with checking for backspace character with nodejs raw stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

I am having trouble figuring out how to check for when a user presses the backspace/delete key when taking raw input.
Here is the code example

```
process.stdin.setRawMode( true );
process.stdin.setEncoding( 'utf8' );
process.stdin.resume();

process.stdin.on( 'data', function( key ){
    /**
     * Trying to check if the delete key is entered
     */
     if( key === '\u0008' ){
         /**
          * code
          */
      }
      process.stdout.write( key );
});
```

The reason I'm am trying to do this is because when i set stdin to rawMode then the hitting the backspace key just moves the cursor (as if the space bar is pressed.).  I found how to emulate deleting by using stdout.moveCursor, and stdout.clearLine, but can't figure out how to check that the delete key was pressed.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do this :

```
if( key.charCodeAt(0) === 127 ){
```