# Trouble with checking for enter character with nodejs raw stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't check for `enter` character. I tried to use `if (key.charCodeAt(0) === 13) console.log('ENTER');` after I saw a same problem with [backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237468/trouble-with-checking-for-backspace-character-with-nodejs-raw-stdin?target=_blank) and it works for me, but I could not understand what is wrong with unicode of `enter`? because `backspace`, `space` and `ctrl-c` works perfectly. I also tried `\ue006` and `\ue007` and they also didn't work.

```
console.clear();

var BACKSPACE = '\u0008';
var CTRL_C = '\u0003';
var ENTER = '\u2386';
var SPACE = '\u0020';

var stdin = process.stdin;

stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

stdin.on('data', (key) => {

    if (key === 'q') process.exit();

    if (key === ENTER) console.log('ENTER');

});

stdin.setRawMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I thought that `enter` key was represented as '\n' symbol, however the correct symbol was '\r' which has Unicode value of '\u000d'